# What makes 'admix' different from 'mix'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

A friend of mine (who, as far as I know, doesn't have English as a first language, though is fluent) mentioned how odd it was that English had the word *admix*, and quoted a dictionary definition that stated that it was a synonym of *mix*. I supposed that an *admix* was a *mix* made **just** by adding two materials together, whereas a *mix* involved stirring.

This is the entry I found:

> ad·mix  
>   tr. & intr.v. ad·mixed, ad·mix·ing, ad·mix·es
>   To mix; blend.

Am I right that the word is redundant, or does it have another use?

Comment: Note that a quick google books search brings up mainly concrete and pharmacological references: `jargon`?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions for both words? What did they say that was the same or different?

Comment: Related: [*Admix* vs. *shuffle*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72838/admix-or-shuffle)

Comment: There are other English word pairs similarly related – where one word can be used as a synonym for the other, but only a prefix differentiates between the two. For example, *join & conjoin*, *camp & encamp*.

Comment: try the noun form: mix and admixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admix), *admix* is being used specifically in *technical* conversations which is, I grant you, not much of a difference. Its etymology is stated as follows:

> late Middle English: back-formation from the obsolete adjective 'admixt', from **Latin admixtus 'mixed together'**, past participle of admiscere, **from ad- 'to' + miscere 'to mix'**

So your friend should technically have blamed Latin (or its ancestors) rather than English :)

English has a number of such curiosities. The weirdest one I can recall are the words *ravel* and *unravel*. The [etymology of ravel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ravel) reads:

> 1580s, "to untangle, unwind," also "to become tangled or confused," from Du. ravelen "to tangle, fray, unweave," from rafel "frayed thread." The seemingly contradictory senses of this word (**ravel and unravel are both synonyms and antonyms**) are reconciled by its roots in weaving and sewing: as threads become unwoven, they get tangled.

Answer (score 4):

In chemistry, we used 'admix' to indicate a substance added and mingled into another. In particular, the term was introduced for the rule of "Always Add Acid" as a safety measure. Admixing acid into solution could result in an exothermic reaction, thus measured and slow addition of the acid might prevent *too much of a punctuated release of heat energy*. To echo other answers, yes, usage of 'admix' lay more within a technical context.

Comment: Also - sodium hydroxide pellets, for example, should always be added (carefully) to water rather than add water to the pellets which, as you indicate for acid, can result in a violent exothermic reaction. So 'admixing' pellets would stipulate adding pellets to water, as you state. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 3):

I often used it, and saw it used, in my field of histopathology (diagnostic study of human tissues). A typical phrase would have been "admixture of blood clot and tissue fragments".

To me, it helped to convey the fact or observation that two or more elements were present together, but still separate. So, in the above example, it meant you could clearly see that there were bits of blood clot and bits of tissue, rather than a mass of bloody tissue with the two elements being indistinguishable from each other.

However, I see that the OED defines it (as a verb): "To mingle with something else; *to add as an ingredient*" (my italics).

Whereas MIX is defined as: "To put together (two or more substances, or groups or classes of things) so that the particles or members of each are more or less evenly diffused among those of the rest"

So that would allow us to say something like, "Prepare a dough of flour and water and then admix the raisins." Just saying "add" the raisins doesn't tell you to add them *and then* mix them together with the existing ingredients.

But with the word "mix" you would have to say "mix in" the raisins. Admittedly, being able to leave out that "in" doesn't exactly make life a lot easier! But hey... maybe in some situations I could imagine it being handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the word 'admix' instead of the word 'mix' you would confuse people.  'Admix' is an archaic word that is rarely used.

Comment: That's not really what the OP is asking. Admix is not really all that archaic either. It's used as technical terminology as well as a shortened form of the word _admixture_.

Comment: I have never come across the word admix or admixture.  I can only assume that its use is very specialised - in other words - that it is a jargon word that is only used in special situations.

Comment: ɑkh ɑhɪm ɑkte wiz bɑɹsu:m  May the Peace be with you as you venture forth to planets unknown.

Answer (score -1):

Admix is an additive mixture (e.g., blue and yellow lights admix to white), as distinct from a subtractive mixture (e.g., paint colors). Submix seems to have a specific audio recording application.

Comment: Can you please add references to reliable sources.